# Enabling ARC causing crashes on button clicks in objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.5

I was working on a project that was working fine before i enabled ARC in it.Now i m getting crashes on button clicks and the tab selection.On my first tab,i have custom cells and inside of each cell,i have buttons.Click on the button will invoke some methods.But after ARC is enabled,"EXC_BAD_ACCESS" is getting on the moment of button click before the methods are invoked.None of the errors are getting logged.This is my code inside the custom cell.

```
                static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CustomCellFor_Dashboard";

            CustomCellFor_Dashboard  *customCell = (CustomCellFor_Dashboard *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
            if (customCell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellFor_Dashboard" owner:self options:nil];
                customCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

            }

             [customCell.sample addTarget:self action:@selector(addActn:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


 return customCell;
```

Can anyone help?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

```
NSArray *custom = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NameOfCustomCellNibFile" owner:self options:nil];
cell = [custom objectAtIndex:0];
```

You have to load the loadNibNamed: with the .xib file's name. I also thought it was with the identifier, but that is regarding the name that is referenced into the cell instead of the nib for the cell so just try this.

Answer (score 1):

In parallel to your concrete problem the more abstract answer to your problem might be to switch on "Break on Exceptions" in XCode.

See here: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions.

(Sorry, if you already knew this.)